# promise chain example is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I wanted to learn about promise chaining and I've try to call to the following function in order from 1 to 3 ,Currently its not working so what am I missing here ?

```
$(function () {
    function doSomething() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            var value = 1;
            resolve(value);
        });
    }


    function doSomething2(){
        return 2;
    };

    function doSomething3(){
        return 3;
    };


    doSomething().then(function (firstResult) {

        var result = "first result " + firstResult;
        alert(result);

    })doSomething2.then(function (secondResult) {
        var secReslut = "second result " + secondResult;
       return alert(secReslut);
    })()doSomething2.then(function (tr)
    {
      alert(tr)
    });


});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `.then` on a promise - it returns a new promise which resolves with the value you return from the `.then`.

Thus, the correct way to chain promises in your example is:

```
doSomething().then(function(firstResult){
     alert(firstResult);
     return doSomething2(); // this could also return a promise over an async value
}).then(function(secondResult){
     alert(secondResult); // alerts 2
     return doSomething3();  
}).then(function(thirdResult){
     alert(result(3);
});
```

---

The reason promise chaining works is because of how `.then` works, its signature as a function is kind of complex, but makes sense when you grasp it:

```
Promise<A> -> (A -> (Promise<B> | B)) -> Promise<B>
```

This looks complicated, but let's analyze it:

- It's a function that operates on a Promise (provided implicitly as the `this`). In our case that's the promise doSomething returns.
- It takes a callback that works on the unwrapped value: what the promise resolved to. It returns a promise over a new type of value (or just a value in our case). In our case, that value is 1. So we have a Promise and we resolve it with 1.
- It returns a promise itself over the value our `then` will resolve - this is why chaining happens. Calling `.then` on it - we provided a function that accepts that 1 as an argument and returned a 2. So we had a 1 -> 2. This returned a promise over the value 2.

A promise in JS is an abstraction over chaining itself. Like others of its kind - it abstracts *sequencing*, think of `then` like a semicolon.

This is in fact why promises are so useful - you hook on asynchronously, just like you returned 2 from the `then` you can return an `$.ajax` call and the chain will only happen when the ajax call completes.

Comment: There is actually a much broader term for this form of chaining with `then`, but I feel that reminding it would only be confusing here. Let me know if you'd like clarification.

Comment: Just last one clarification,if you start in doSomething function you should call to the next function in the chain inside the then ? always ,and if you should send parameters from one to another how should I do that?can you please provide example?

Comment: Yes, always. You should check out Domenic Denicula's "You're missing the point of promises" article it should clarify this :)

Comment: One last question :) there is some ready JSfiddle or some code that I can just copy paste to debug and learn promises better,all the code which I find is just unrelated example which you cannot use as part from stand along program and debug it...Thanks in advance! voted up and mark as complicted