# convert from video uri to blob is not working on iOS using ionic framework

Tags: ios, angular, file, ionic-framework, file-upload

I am using the following code to convert the video file to blob for iOS.

```
    Takevideo()
      {
          const options: CameraOptions = {
            sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, 
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.VIDEO      
          }
            this.camera.getPicture(options).then(async (videoUrl) => {
              debugger;
              this.selectvideopath=null;
              var filename = videoUrl.substr(videoUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
              var dirpath = videoUrl.substr(0, videoUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    
              dirpath = dirpath.includes("file://") ? dirpath : "file://" + dirpath;
              try {
                var dirUrl = await this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl(dirpath);
                var retrievedFile = await this.file.getFile(dirUrl, filename, {});
                this.makeFileIntoBlob(retrievedFile.nativeURL);
              } catch(err) {
                return this.ionLoader.showAlert("Something went wrong.");
              }
             
             }, (err) => {
              // Handle error
             });
      }
    
      makeFileIntoBlob(_imagePath) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          console.log("makefileintoblob", +_imagePath);
          let fileName = "";
          this.file
            .resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(_imagePath)
            .then(fileEntry => {
              let { name, nativeURL } = fileEntry;
    
              let path = nativeURL.substring(0, nativeURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
              console.log("path", path);
              console.log("fileName", name);
    
              fileName = name;
    
              var buffer=this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(path, name);
              console.log("makefileintoblob buffer: " +buffer);
              this.Videodatas.push({vdodata:buffer});
              return this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(path, name);
            })
            .then(buffer => {
              this.ionLoader.showAlert('2:'+buffer);
              console.log("makefileintoblob buffernew: " +buffer);
              let imgBlob = new Blob([buffer], {
                type: "video/MOV"
              });
              console.log(imgBlob.type, imgBlob.size);
              resolve({
                fileName,
                imgBlob
              });
            })
            .catch(e => reject(e));
        });
      }
```

But the following block is not executed.

```
    .then(buffer => {
              this.ionLoader.showAlert('2:'+buffer);
              console.log("makefileintoblob buffernew: " +buffer);
              let imgBlob = new Blob([buffer], {
                type: "video/MOV"
              });
              console.log(imgBlob.type, imgBlob.size);
              resolve({
                fileName,
                imgBlob
              });
```

I have already installed the packages:
npm install --save @ionic-native/file-transfer
npm install cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install cordova-plugin-file

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [promise chain example is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971617/promise-chain-example-is-not-working)

Comment: No. this is not

Comment: The following path is my iOS _imagePath(video path) ```path:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4351D038-A4D6-4DE2-9525-4DA1F3D94618/tmp/cdv_photo_1676367898.MOV```

and i can see the followings in my log:
```To Native Cordova ->  File resolveLocalFileSystemURI File505249408 ["options": [file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D296C612-F50B-4426-9A48-5F21C0D6F1A5/tmp]]```. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot convert the video to blob for iOS. So I send the video to server through API. Find the link below:

[upload file to server using ionic framework and web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105158/upload-file-to-server-using-ionic-framework-and-web-api/75730281#75730281)